# Cross Origin error in Firebase authentication

Tags: authentication, firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

Some times I get a cross origin error, while logging in using `$firebaseAuth`:

```
var loginObj = $firebaseAuth(firebaseRef);
        loginObj.$authWithPassword( {
            email: logindata.username,
            password: logindata.password
        }).then(function (user) {
            success(user);
        }, function (error) {

            failure(error);
        });
```

I am receiving the following error, While login.

> https://auth.firebase.com/v2/test-innit-7856/auth/password?&email=test@test.com&password=test&v=js-2.1.0&transport=json&suppress_status_codes=true
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Time-out)
>   (index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://auth.firebase.com/v2/test-innit-7856/auth/password?&email=test@test.com&password=test&v=js-2.1.0&transport=json&suppress_status_codes=true. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://test-innit-7856.firebaseapp.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 504

Comment: It's likely that this error emerged while a server was being restarted, given a reconfiguration that has been rolling out. This should be ephemeral, but looks like adding some retry logic to the client would be useful. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: This is now happening to me all of a sudden.