# Firebase Fetch - No Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, cors

I'm developing an app with `React + Redux` and I have my `JSON` database within a `Firebase` DB.
To do this I'm tryin to `fetch` my data from a valid URL (validated from Firebase simulator)

```
let firebase = 'https://******.firebaseio.com/**/*/***/*' 
    return (dispatch) => {
        return fetch(firebase)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => dispatch({ type: 'GET_JSON', payload: json }))
    }
```

This returns to me the error:

> Fetch API cannot load https://console.firebase.google.com/project/****/database/data/**/*/***/*. Redirect from 'https://console.firebase.google.com/project/****/database/data/**/*/***/*' to 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?ltmpl=firebase&osid=1&passive=true…ole.firebase.google.com/project/****/database/data/**/*/***/*' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

I've tried many solutions, like adding to fetch's second argument `{ mode: 'no-cors', credentials: 'same-origin'}`, but when I try this i get `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`.

What am I missing?

Comment: might be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948190/cross-origin-error-in-firebase-authentication

Comment: I had the same problem and I solved it by passing `{
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }` to `fetch` as the second argument.

Answer (score 12):

```
likely error that arise to  cors blocked when using firebase is
when you initiate a put or get request with an incomplete firebase url
e.g
// wrong form
 this.http.get('https://******.firebaseio.com/data')   //this will throw an exception

// correct form                                                    
  this.http.get('https://******.firebaseio.com/data.json')
```

Comment: It was happening with me when i had spelling mistake in url

Comment: This helped. Thank you. I was missing `.json` at the end.

Comment:   thanks, and the ".json" part is mandatory..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a `serviceworker` implementation of `fetch`

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {

fetch(e.request) // valid arg && works with firebase

fetch(e.request.url) // valid arg but will cause access-control error!

}
```

Answer (score -6):

For a simple request to be allowed cross-domain, the server simply needs to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response.

Also refer this turorial, if you have any doubts

[Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr)

[Using CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).