# CORS problem - Access to fetch at *** from origin *** has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - PUT request to Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have CORS problem, I am sending an put request for updating data - posts into Firebase with React:

```
const submitHandler = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const err = validate();
        if(err === false) {
            setFormData(formData)
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    title: title,
                    url: url,
                    author: author,
                    description: description})
            };
            fetch(`https://blog-d8b04-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/posts/${postName}`, requestOptions)
                .then(response => {response.json(); console.log(response)})
                .then(data => console.log(data));
            setFormData(initialState);
        }
    }
```

I have this notification error in console

```
Access to fetch at 'https://blog-d8b04-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/posts/-MX1-Df4t59Y3DnyWUzB' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
EditPost.js:58 PUT https://blog-d8b04-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/posts/-MX1-Df4t59Y3DnyWUzB net::ERR_FAILED
```

With post request - to add new posts everything is working fine.
Has someone solution for this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Fetch - No Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081984/firebase-fetch-no-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: Unfortunately, not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you access your database over HTTPS, you need to access the JSON version of your data by appending `.json` to your database URL, like this:

```
fetch(`https://blog-d8b04-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/posts/${postName}.json`, requestOptions)
  .then(response => {response.json(); console.log(response)})
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

You should also update your database rules because your database is world readable and writable.

Answer (score -2):

My solution is turn off Cors Policy of browser. This error because backend don't allow access from HTTP connect:

With windows run this command in cmd:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
```

With macbook :

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security
```

Comment: This isn't a practical solution. It is unreasonable to ask end users to disable security features in their browsers just to use a website they are visiting.